# A microkernel fully hardcoded in hardware?

Tags: cpu, os-kernel

Does there exist a (micro-)kernel of an operating system that is fully implemented in hardware? That is, a kernel that is not stored in RAM, and loaded into CPU registers after an interrupt or system call, but is instead a fully hardcoded part of the CPU itself, so that a system call/interrupt never leads to a context switch?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key search terms here are FPGA and ASIC, since at this point the OS is no longer running on instructions executed by a CPU in the conventional sense.

Here is a relevant result I found with a quick Google search on `microkernel fpga` and `os kernel fpga`:

Susanna Nordström et al. [Application Specific Real-Time Microkernel in Hardware](https://www.design-reuse.com/articles/10722/application-specific-real-time-microkernel-in-hardware.html).

> In the RTU, the scheduling, inter process communication, interrupt management, resource management, synchronization and time management control are implemented in hardware (using VHDL).

This paper goes a step further and describes an OS-like environment for FPGA programs themselves: Kermin Fleming et al. [The LEAP FPGA Operating System](https://people.csail.mit.edu/emer/papers/2014.09.fpl.leap_overview.pdf).

> Like a software operating environment, LEAP provides both basic device abstractions for FPGAs and a collection of standard I/O and memory management services.